# expand.grid very big vectors exceeding memory limit

Tags: r, memory, quantile, weighted-average

I have a problem with R.
I have 6 vectors of data. Each vector will have weight.
I need to calculate the quantile of each possible scenarios.
For example :

```
v1=c(1,2)
v2=c(0,5)
weights=c(1/3,2/3)
```

I would normally use :

```
scenarios=data.matrix(expand.grid(v1,v2))
results=scenarios %*% weights
```

And finally to get all the quantiles from 1% to 100% :

```
quantiles=quantile(results,seq(0.01,1,0.01),names=FALSE)
```

The problem is that I have 6 vectors of : 51,236,234,71,7 and 8 obs respectively, which would give me a vector of 11 G obs...

I get the error from R that I exceed the memory limit with a vector of 47 Gb...

Do you see some alternative that I can use to bypass this big matrix? I'm thinking like a loop within each value one vector and write the result in a document.
But then I don't know how i would calculate the percentile of these separate files...

Comment: just a suggestion for you to chew over: your population size is really really huge. would you consider performing sampling to estimate your population pdf?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than generate the whole population, how about sampling to generate your pdf?

```
N <- 1e6
scenarios <- unique(matrix(c(sample(1:51, N, replace=T),
    sample(1:236, N, replace=T),
    sample(1:234, N, replace=T),    
    sample(1:71, N, replace=T),
    sample(1:7, N, replace=T),
    sample(1:8, N, replace=T)), nrow=N))
N <- nrow(scenarios)
weights <- matrix(rep(1/6, 6))
quantiles <- quantile(scenarios %*% weights, seq(0.01,1,0.01), names=FALSE)
```

if OP strictly wants the whole population, I will take this post down

Comment: Hi thank you Chinson12! How could i know what is the distribution of my vectors? My vectors are not (1,2,3...51),(1,2,...,251),... They are more like (0.0714,0.02156,0.0068,...) then how could i use the sample function with my vectors ? Im gonna look to your solution more in details and see what i can change to adapt it to my needs. But i was pretty sure from the begining that sampling would be needed here !

Answer (score 1):

Alright !! Thanks for your help guys !
Looks like sampling was the way to go !

Heres the code i use at the end with chinson12's help !
I did a bootstrap to see if the sampling converges towards the right value !

```
N=1e6
B=2
results = c(1:100)
for ( i in 1:B){
     scenarios=unique(matrix(c(sample(v1,N,replace=T),sample(v2,N,replace=T),sample(v3,N,replace=T),
                      sample(v4,N,replace=T),sample(v5,N,replace=T),sample(v6,N,replace=T)),nrow = N))
     weightedSum = round(scenarios %*% weights,4)
     results=cbind(results,quantile(weightedSum ,seq(0.01,1,0.01),names=FALSE))
}
write(t(results),"ouput.txt",ncolumns = B + 1)
```

The output file looks great ! To 4 digits places, all of my percentiles are the same ! So they converges to a value at least !

This being said, are those percentiles unbiased for my population percentiles ?

Thanks

Comment: That last question you will need to search and/or post in stat exchange :)